# How to create Work items (tasks, bugs, etc) using ruby for an Azure DevOps project?

Tags: ruby, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any Ruby API that would be used to create work items in my ADS project?

Which api should I use to create or update work items in Azure DevOps using ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unofficial Ruby library that wrap the Azure DevOps api, you can find it [here](https://gitlab.com/michaelsabo/ruby_vsts), is not look like it's maintained.

Another option is to use [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops) with Ruby, and run it like every HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Ruby API, but can use the standard REST API in ruby code to create work item in ado project. Below links with help you with the details -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/index?branch=master&view=Azure%20DevOps

Work item tracking Service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0